# Incorrect router address resulting in stuck liquidity

Tags: solidity, transactions, router, liquidity

I accidentally added liquidity to a swap using the incorrect router address. Is there a way to retrieve the liquidity? I appreciate any help - even if you tell me it's impossible!

This is the token: https://explorer.dogechain.dog/address/0x74C5f46d3C17D90dB6b98cfAe4234f20e83be866

Error message when withdrawing liquidity:
https://explorer.dogechain.dog/tx/0x078ec4f03eadfc14180fb0307fd11adf7564472bceef44c93536b23e31306256

LP Address:
https://explorer.dogechain.dog/token/0xa879e50ed958eF0DB8C47F090201E2F2b37694f5/token-transfers